# How to avoid from multiple times data being appended to the select tag

Tags: jquery

On a Ajax Request ,I am getting this response  from a server

```
{
    "screen": [
        {
            "screen_name": "SCR1",
            "screen_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "screen_name": "SCR2",
            "screen_id": "2"
        },
        {
            "screen_name": "SCR3",
            "screen_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "screen_name": "SCR4",
            "screen_id": "4"
        },
        {
            "screen_name": "SCR5",
            "screen_id": "5"
        },
        {
            "screen_name": "BIGSCR",
            "screen_id": "6"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem i am facing is that everytime i click on the drop down , data is being appended multiple times to the select HTML named SCname

I am appending this data to a select tag and the screen looks this way

[image]

This is my code

```
$(document).on("click", "#SCname", function() {
     var htmloptions = '';        
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url+'/OMS/oms1/getscreens?location_id='+location_id,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        success: function(response) {
            var jsondata = JSON.stringify(response);
            jsondata = JSON.parse(jsondata);
        for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.screen.length; i++) {
        var screenName = jsondata.screen[i].screen_name.trim();
        var screenId = jsondata.screen[i].screen_id.trim();
        htmloptions+='<option value="'+screenId+'">'+screenName+'</option>';

    }

    $('#SCname').append(htmloptions);

        },
        error: function(e) {

            alert('into error');

        }
    });

});


                <select name="" id="SCname">
                    <option> Write Screen Name</option>
                </select>
```

Even though i am clearing the htmloptipns every time , but still Data is being appended to it multiple times , could anybody please let me know how to avoid that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending data to `$('#SCname')` each time you click on the select, without resetting it. Clearing `htmloptions` is not enough since it's only a local variable. Reset the content of `$('#SCname')` before appending the new values.

Comment: Thank you very much , i solved this by using this line $('#SCname').empty();